# How to align different Tablix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a SSRS report in which i need to align multiple tablix in same Order as i need to export to EXCEL

The other tablix's is just a copy of the first tablix with only change of data set.But all the tablix will have same Columns.I need to align each column to the respective column in the other tablix. Can anyone help me in this?

After exporting in to excel,column1 of Tablix1 is not in Sync with Column1 of Tablix2,they are created in different Columns in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you are proposing with two separate tablixes.  I may be wrong, but I think you would need to change the underlying dataset or query being used to return the data (probably need to do a UNION or something) and display all of the data in the SAME tablix, which shouldn't be a huge problem since you are using the same columns.  If you do it this way, you would use your row groupings to effectively section of the tablix so that the data has some separation.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps will work.

1. Select 1st Tablix and open the property window. Set property Location->Left=0
2. Do the same for 2nd tablix.
3. Now select cell one by one of the 1st  tablix and open the property window. Set property
   size->Width="required width of the cell and keep the maximum decimal places upto 2 decimal places"
4. Do the same for 2nd Tablix

Answer (score 0):

I have just had to sort this issue.  I had multiple tablix's underneath each other with various text boxes for labelling and had them inside rectangles.  I did as suggested above lining everything to 0.0 on the location Left and checking that every single cell in every single column was the same width as the cell in the tablix directly above and below it.  However when exported to excel I still had 2 or 3 blank columns hidden between each data column.  In the end I removed all of the rectangles and just used the tablix's and text boxes.  Everything was aligned to 0.0 location left, and all text boxes were the same width as the tablix's.  This time when I exported to excel there were no extra blank columns.